# UnityAR Walking Detect(without shaking)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I want to develop a AR game that detects when I walk (but doesn't work when I shake). As we walk, objects will spawn around us (they should not spawn when we shake them) and we will blow them up. I couldn't find a good source. can you help?

```
void Update()
{
    
    float velocityZDifference = Mathf.Abs(gameManager.velocityZ - previousVelocityZ);

    if (gameManager.velocityZ < 0.8f && gameManager.velocityZ > 0.09f && velocityZDifference < 0.1f)
    {
        
        if (Time.timeSinceLevelLoad - time > Random.Range(3, 10))
        {
            RandomPrefab();
            time = (int)Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
        }
    }

    previousVelocityZ = gameManager.velocityZ;
}
```